# M.2 Compatibility for Dell 7559

Tags: ssd, compatibility, dell-inspiron, m.2

I just wanted to check if the M.2 SU800 M.2 2280 from ADATA would be compatible with the Dell Inspiron 15 7559. I'm pretty new to the M.2 standard (I've never had one) and it confuses me a bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had opened one of the Dell Inspiron 7000 series to repair some of its parts and from my experience M.2 2280 storages are compatible with these models. Now that you are upgrading, I would install a faster NVME version to gain up to 3-6 times faster storage speed.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this lap only supports SATA 3 M.2

Answer (score 0):

Dell 7559 is not compatible with NVME drives!

Comment: Welcome to superuser, due to the  different views , you may be correct but a reference link at least would settle the question. thankyou for coming to superuser.